# User defined match terms for sting distance calculation in R

Tags: r, function, string-matching, stringdist

There are many choices of string distance calculation methods in R in package `{stringdist}` (https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/stringdist/stringdist.pdf), very curious about if it is possible to include user defined match items by using `regex` or some other ways in the `Jaro` or `Jaro-Winker` distance calculations? If not, is there any other packages provide this kind of function?

For example:
for string `"USA Starwar Corporation"` `(a)`, `"US Starwar Corporation"` `(b)`, `"United States Starwar Corporation"` `(c)` currently the Jaro distances between `((a),(b)),((b),(c)),((a),(c))` are respectively `0.01449275, 0.2020202, 0.216513`. Is there any way to define `"USA"` matches `"US"` matches`"United States"` in the calculation and therefore the distance could be `0,0,0`?

Thanks!